# How can I get this equation? $F(x+yd\phi, y+xd\phi) = F(x,y) + (y\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}} + x\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}})d\phi$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

This maybe a very stupid question. I forgot a lot of things about calculus :(

$F(x, y)$ is an differentiable function. Anybody could explain me why I could get the following equation ?

$$F(x+yd\phi, y+xd\phi) = F(x,y) + (y\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}} + x\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}})d\phi.$$

Comment: what is $\phi$, and $d\phi$?

Comment: @JustinBenfield $\phi$ is any independent variabl. $d\phi$ is $\delta\phi$.

Comment: What is $\delta\phi$? Is this a change of variables expression?

Comment: @JustinBenfield yes

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is some confusions in the notations you used. Furthermore, is the equation missing some terms and symbols ?

There are some problems in the equation as stated currently : 
$$
F(x+yd\phi, y+xd\phi) = F(x,y) + (y\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}} + x\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}})d\phi
$$

For example, $F(x+yd\phi, y+xd\phi)$ is a number, while $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}}$ is a function.

I'm guessing that the result you want is only the definition of a differentiable function :
$$
 F(a+h_1, b+h_2) = F(a,b) + d_{(a,b)}F \cdot (h_1,h_2) + o(||(h_1,h_2)||)
$$

Applied here with $(a,b) = (x,y)$ and $(h_1,h_2) = (yd\phi, xd\phi)$, we get :
$$
 F(x+yd\phi, y+xd\phi) = F(x,y) + d_{(x,y)}F \cdot (yd\phi, xd\phi) + o(||(yd\phi, xd\phi)||)
$$
Recalling that :
$$
 d_{(x,y)}F \cdot (yd\phi, xd\phi) = \frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}}(x,y) \cdot yd\phi + \frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}}(x,y) \cdot xd\phi
$$
We finally get :
$$
F(x+yd\phi, y+xd\phi) = F(x,y) + \left(y\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}}(x,y) + x\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}}(x,y)\right) d\phi + o(||(yd\phi, xd\phi)||)
$$

Which is what I understood your equation meant.